# Interior piece for 2011 Corolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, part-identification

I replaced the carpet on my 2011 Corolla and cannot remember where this piece goes.  Anybody ever seen something like this?[image]

Comment: Looks like it would either go in the scrap metal pile or waste bin if you don't have a scrap pile. Seriously tho it is a  clip of some type. Either used for carpet or used to hold part of the center console together